# getting random images on click of reset button in android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android  game application named Bingo.I have implemented the basic functionality.I have done tapping part also.Problem is that when i click on reset all the tapped images should be changed randomly.Can anybody tell me how should i pursue

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the rules of the game and if you have n different images to put on n places randomly. But to me it sounds somehow similar to this. To distribute the images in such a case I used permutations. You can either generate all of them once, store them and then with one random number r get the rTh permutation - or - if there are too many places you might have to create the permutation each time on the fly. Use NSMutableArray to store the iTh new random number and to check if a number already has been chosen...

To give a more concrete advice, one would have to understand the problem better....

Comment: user 381874 whats ur email id

Comment: explain your problem better. Is it that you want to know how to get the images associated or is is more into the direction I suggested? Start your explanation with a small example, so that we can help - you will see - it is not as hard as you may think!